# Drawing a cube on the top right of a window opengl (and make it stay there)

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw a cube in `opengl` that will allow me to change the view when we press on of its faces (Like in `Unity3D`, `Autocad`), here is some images for both softwares :

[image]

[image: Unity3D]

This is what I tried :

```
void GLWidget::drawViewCube(float x, float y, float z, float t, float posX, float posY){
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     //std::cout << " x : " << x << ", y : " << y << ", z : " << z;
     glVertex3f(x+posX+t,y+posY-t,z+t);
     glVertex3f(x+posX-t,y+posY-t,z+t);
     glVertex3f(x+posX-t,y+posY+t,z+t);
     glVertex3f(x+posX+t,y+posY+t,z+t);

     glVertex3f(x+posX+t,y+posY+t,z+t);
     .
     .
     .
     // Just drawing a cube

}
```

And this is how I'm calling it :

```
drawViewCube(-depX,-depY,-zoom-590, 0.5, -0.03 * height(), 0.03 * width());
```

So i'm drawing it like a normal cube, but i'm making it follow the camera with `depX` and `depY` ( which are the deplacements of my camera), and with `zoom` also. WIth this the cube is following my camera and always stays at the same position (which is what we want,right?) i'm also trying to make it stay inside the window when we extend the window with `height()` and `width()`, but this is not really working, when i extend the window it doesn't stay at the some place (top right) but this is not the biggest problem, the real problem is when i rotate my camera ...

I think that I should try to draw using the Matrix of my view so I can let it stay at the same place, but I'm not that good at opengl ... 
So if anyone has any idea about this thing, please let me know.

PS : I only want to draw the cube for now, I'll think about how to make pressing on it change the view later.

Comment: it's probably easier to let it ignore the camera altogether and apply the rotation separately

Comment: Yes, but as I said, i'm not very good at using the View Matrix, if you could explain how I can do that, it would be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You should establish a nice, fixed coordinate system you can draw your cube in by setting the projection and modelview accordingly. This can be done for example as follows in your drawViewCube method:

```
//store current projection matrix, load orthographic projection
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0); // (0,0) set to upper left corner

//store current modelview and load identity transform
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

//disable depth testing so the quad is always on top
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//draw quad in coordinate system (0,0)->(1,1) at z=0
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(0.1,0.1,0.0);
glVertex3f(0.2,0.1,0.0);
glVertex3f(0.2,0.2,0.0);
glVertex3f(0.1,0.2,0.0);
glEnd();

//re-enable depth testing
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//restore modelview and projection to previous state
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Note that this assumes that matrix mode is GL_MODELVIEW initially. Also you should read up about modelview and projection somewhere. (or you'll likely run into more trouble ;) )

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I actually need a cube that will rotate when I rotate the camera (look at first picture)

Comment: Oh, now i understand ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this is more complicated.
If your cube should align to the global coordinate system, i think you need to put up a matrix that represents the same rotation as the view matrix, but without scale or translation. Maybe you can play with your camera routine and only setup the rotation until you get a satisfactory rendering of a cube in your "main screen". Then you only need to restrict the viewport as shown, apply these settings and draw the cube.